# Implementing the Number of Swaps and Comparisons

Tags: python, bubble-sort

```
def bubbleSort(randnums):
    swpcount, compcount = 0, 0
    for numbers in range(len(randnums)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(numbers):
            compcount +=1
            if randnums[i]>randnums[i+1]:
                swpcount +=1
                mash = randnums[i]
                randnums[i] = randnums[i+1]
                randnums[i+1] = mash
    return swpcount, compcount
swpcount, compcount = bubbleSort(randnums)
```

When I run the function it returns 0 for number of swaps. Number of comparisons is correct. How do I return the correct number of swaps?

Comment: when I run the program it returns 0 for number of swaps. Number of comparisons is correct. Im just having trouble fixing my swaps count

Comment: Works for me. Note that swapping variables can be done as `randnums[i], randnums[i+1] = randnums[i+1], randnums[i]`

Comment: I didn't see an error. What's your `randnums`?

Comment: Interesting, it's definitely returning 0 for me but displaying the comps correctly. randnums is a list of randomly generated float nums

Comment: Check your looping constructs a bit more carefully